# Adding Numbers to get the target Numbers

Tags: sql-server

I am in need of a Formula for Grace Marks for Ms. SQL query:

5 grace marks are given to a subject, that can be simple but the requirement is for only those students who need grace marks. e.g. the passing marks are 45, and if a student's marks are 42 he only get 3 marks not 5.

There is a table contains STUDENT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, MARKS and GRACE MARKS Column.

The other table contains SUBJECT_ID, SUBJECT_Name, TOTAL MARKS and MINIMUM PASSING MARKS

Scenario:
Subject_1
Total Marks 100;
Minimum Pass Marks 45;

Students in Subject_1:
Student_1 Marks   35
Student_2 Marks   42
Student_3 Marks   44

What I want is that if total 5 grace marks are given to SUBJECT_1 then only Student_1,Student_2 and Students_3 should get 0,3,1 respectively.

Please help

Regards,

Comment: please add some more details like the existing table structure, existing data. what is the expected output and your tries

Comment: Agreed @ps_prakash02, it's netiquette to provide as many details as possible when asking for help.

Comment: UPDATE StudentMark SET GraceMarks = 45 - Marks
WHERE Marks >= 40 and Marks < 45

SELECT Student_Id, Marks, 45 - Marks
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE Marks >= 40 and Marks < 45
UNION
SELECT Student_Id, Marks, 0
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE Marks >= 45

Comment: please check the questions again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this

```
SELECT a.Student_Id, a.Subject_Id, b.Subject_Name, 
       a.Marks, b.Total_Marks, b.Minimum_Passing_Marks, 
       case 
           when a.Marks >= b.Minimum_Passing_Marks then 0
           when (b.Minimum_Passing_Marks - a.Marks) <= a.Grace_Marks then (b.Minimum_Passing_Marks - a.Marks)
           else 0 
       end Grace_Marks
    FROM StudentMarks a
    INNER JOIN Subject b ON a.Subject_Id = b.Subject_Id
```